# Chrome cant find domain, curl can find domain

Tags: windows, http, curl, http-status-code-404

I am trying to make a request to a server in chrome. I keep getting a 404 error whenever I attempt to connect. When I use curl (which on Windows is an alias for Invoke-WebRequest) I correctly get a response. I have copied the chrome request header exactly into my curl request, so why does the browser fail when curl succeeds.

Comment: Do other browsers also unable to find the domain?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio just checked in Microsoft Edge, was not able to find the domain. Only curl has succeeded in finding the domain.

Comment: Although curl can reach the domain, arre you able to ping it?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I am able to ping the hostname

Comment: If possible can you post the address of the domain?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I can't. It is a private host that isn't publicly accessible.

Comment: Check if there is any difference when using http and https with the domain?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio with http the error says the site cannot be reached and does not give an error code. With https it says the page cannot be found and give a 404 error code.